# DC amps fluctuating when measuring?

Tags: dc, amperage

So as some background, I have a bathroom exhaust fan with a built-in Bluetooth speaker. By default, the speaker is powered only when the light is on, but my goal is to have that on all the time.

The manufacturer was able to tell me that the speaker is powered by 8v, which I was able to confirm via multimeter. The speaker itself is rated for 3W; does that mean that it should require 350mA?

I tried to get a measurement of the current (using the A⎓ on my multimeter) coming from the existing line just to be sure, and I got very confused. It cycles in repeated steps: (roughly) 100mA, 200mA, 400mA, 600mA, 800mA, 1A, then back again.

Does this make sense to anyone? I wasn't able to find anything online about what this means. How can I measure the amperage so that I can ensure I get the correct adapter/transformer for this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A load needs to be tested under known conditions, minimizing as many variables as possible. When trying to determine maximum power requirements, those conditions need to simulate a worse-case situation.

In your case, you would set up your experiment to operate with an input of known frequency and amplitude(the "Control"), and a possibly varying gain(the volume level; the "Variable"), to see how much current the circuit requires at maximum or near-maximum volume levels. When measuring current, the meter should be connected in series between the power source and the load.

If you don't have a known-stable input source(for example, a function generator or audio test-tone), then your experiment cannot produce usable results.

If both the amplifier and Bluetooth receiver are powered by the same low-voltage input, then there is certainly a regulator in place before the Bluetooth/controller circuit, and amplifier circuits are generally very lenient in their operating voltage, so you should be able to get away with a 6 to 9 Volt supply at 1 Amp of current if the amplifier only puts out 3 Watts or less.

Comment: Hm... I know some of those words. That doesn't explain the jumping current, though; being that it's DC, shouldn't it be relatively stable, especially without a draw? If I put it against a 9v battery, for instance, there's a set amperage (which slowly decreases, but still relatively stable). Certainly there's some layman's way of figuring out what adapter specs I should be shooting for?

Comment: @Morgon - Haha, sorry, this is EE.se, so I am used to using engineering terminology, and always try to answer questions as broadly as I can in order to help others that may have similar but different problems to yours.  In your case, you should link a device to the Bluetooth and play a test-tone through the amplifier at high-ish volume and test the current at that point.  It should be steady.

Comment: @Morgon - Also, specific to your case, if both the amplifier and Bluetooth receiver are powered by the same low-voltage input, then there is certainly a regulator in place before the Bluetooth/controller circuit, while amplifier circuits are generally very lenient in their operating voltage.  You should be able to get away with a 6 to 9 Volt supply at 1 Amp of current if the amplifier only puts out 3 Watts...

Comment: Okay, that's very helpful - thank you. I wasn't sure how specific "8v" would be, as the output was pretty steady when I was testing. As for monitoring while playing a test tone, I got no joy - even while it was playing, the amps continued to fluctuate: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tu0cq6z6c58csdv/IMG_5176.mov?dl=0 (sound removed, as it would just be a fan and a 1000Hz tone)

Comment: Also, if it helps understand how this is normally powered, the wiring diagram is here on page 5: https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/d1/d1d02566-89b4-4e99-8f08-303ab9395907.pdf . I don't have access to the "controller" since the fan is already mounted and framed up; I have the pigtails to run external power once I know how I'm actually going to power it. 9v @1a is easy if you really think I can get away with it.

Comment: @Morgon - This is a DC supply, and you are measuring current through the high current port on your meter and the GND  lead, with the meter set to DC current, right?

Comment: @Morgon - Are you even sure that the supply to your targeted circuits is a DC supply, and not AC that is later rectified?  Have you examined the circuits at all? It would be helpful if you could provided at lease one photo or link to a photo....

Comment: Yes, I'm measuring DC (A⎓ on my meter) with the correct leads, as far as I have been able to tell about my meter. Although now I'm questioning whether I am using my multimeter correctly, and this is slightly embarrassing. When I tried to test A~, the speaker would turn off when I probed it. I thought the meter is just monitoring, but it's completing a circuit, isn't it... Since the connection this has two wires, I put one lead on each wire. Now I'm totally unsure how to test this; anything I've seen on YT has a single wire.

Comment: Are you probing across the speaker or power terminals?  When measuring current, the meter should be connected in series between the power source and the load, not across the positive and negative terminals.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P660hTqkGiY

Comment: Thanks for walking me through that; I was able to get this connected with a 9V @1A adapter and the two-post connector. If you can edit your answer to reference what you mentioned in the comments, I'm happy to mark this as solved!

Comment: @Morgon - Edited as suggested.